# Creating a date calculated field in tableau

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I have a starting date, and an end date in tableau, is there a way to create a calculated field with all date (months) ranging from my start date to my end date?

Comment: Could you add some context to the problem and what you have tried already? It would help to give you a better answer

Comment: I have a Start and End dates, I'm trying to create a calculated field that contains every month between said start and end dates. I have 2017 to 2019, I am trying to create filed that has January 2017 to December 2019 (including every month in between). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a visual solution, if you place a Month(date) discrete dimension in your columns bar, right click on it and click on 'Show missing values'. That would force nulls to show, e.g.
[image]

Although what you have specifically asked for sounds like you're looking to do 'data densification' or 'data padding'. You'd have to think about how that generated data would relate to the existing data.

It might also be easier to create a static file with the month/year in columns and (left) join that to the data set you are using. Then you have something you can reuse. I'd recommend that approach.

Comment: Is this seriously the recommended way? Strange that this isn't possible more naturally with the program... either way, thanks for the tip.